# Fix Asus G73Jw bricked

Tags: asus-laptop

hope can help me guys.

I bricked my Asus G73Jw when update bios from NTFS partiton (yes, i don't read doc...)

Unfortunately flashing from a NTFS formatted disk often seems to end in corrupted/wiped Bios. They really should include in the instructions "use a FAT32 USB disk if flashing the BIOS". Doesn't say that anywhere in the manual, though time and time again failed flashes are on NTFS.

So I need to fix my bricked G73Jw without taking it to customer service or any kind of this because i am located in México,

The light power never turn on even if i plug to energy, its completly dead

I have tried boot in many ways (external hd, usb, ctrl + home) but it simple dont turn on, its dead bricked.

¿any suggestions?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Its called a crisis recovery, some suggestions here...https://rog.asus.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-10273.html

Comment: @Moab thanks, but my laptop don't turn any light on

Comment: Then there is another problem besides the bios.